# What is meant by saying $I=(5a+b\sqrt{5}) $ is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Hi I am wondering if someone can explain something in my notes.

It says, consider $$\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{5})=\{a+b\sqrt{5}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

then $$I=\{5a+b\sqrt{5}: a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ is an ideal. Without verifying axioms, this can be seen by noting it is simply the principal ideal $(\sqrt{5})$

My question is; because I am rather new to rings so I am a bit confused.

I know a principal ideal is something of the form $(n)=(rn)$ where $r \in R$ i.e. just basically all the multiples under the multiplication ring operation.

So for example $$(5)=(-,,..-5,0,5,10,15,…)=\{5n: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

so $(\sqrt{5})=(\sqrt{5}n)$

so where does the extra $5a$ come from/ why is that allowed? it doesn't change the ideal?

Comment: Can you clarify the ring that you're considering?  Is it $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}] = \{ a + b\sqrt{5} \mid a,b \in \Bbb{Z} \}$?

Comment: yes thats the one

Comment: A word about notation:  $(n) = \{ rn \mid r \in R \}$, the ideal of $R$-multiples of $n$, but this is not the same as $(rn)$, the ideal of $R$-multiples of $rn$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal can be generated by more than one element.  In your case,
$$
I = (5, \sqrt{5}) = \{ 5a + \sqrt{5}b \mid a,b \in \Bbb{Z} \}.
$$
Even though it's presented as generated by two elements, it turns out in this case that the ideal is generated by a single element (that's what *principal* means).  What does it mean to be *generated* by an element $x$?  It means that any element of $I$ can be written as a multiple $rx$, where $r$ can be any element of the ring.
Since
$$
5a + \sqrt{5}b = ( b + \sqrt{5}a ) \sqrt{5},
$$
every element of $I$ is a multiple of $\sqrt{5}$.  Thus,
$$
I = (\sqrt{5}).
$$

Comment: Ah so its just saying $(\sqrt{5})=(element in Ring)(\sqrt{5})=(a+b\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{5}) =(\sqrt{5}a+5b) \in I$ ?

Comment: Yeah.  That's what the ideal notation $(x)$ means.  The challenge in this problem is to find the particular $x=\sqrt{5}$ so that every element of the ideal is a multiple of it.

Answer (score 2):

$5a + b\sqrt{5} = (\sqrt{5}a + b) \sqrt{5}$

Comment: so the multiple n need not be in Z?

Comment: That's right: a principal ideal in a ring $R$ comprises all elements $xa$ for some given $a \in R$ and any $x \in R$.